# Como apagar uma linha de print especifica no cmd Python

Tags: python-3.x

Ultimamente tem me aparecido um erro ao usar a lib progressbar2 para criar uma barra no windows 10.

Quando meto em tela cheia ou diminuo o tamanho ele começa a criar barras:

[image: 1] Erro

Resolvi o erro limpando o cmd com a lib os mas eu precisava que fossem mostrados algumas informações anteriores.

Com esta experiência aprecevi-me que o erro tem a haver com o aumento e diminuo do numero de linhas e dai ele não apagar a linha com o comando \r.

Oque eu gostaria de fazer era apagar as linhas que estivessem debaixo de uma linha especifica no caso apareceria 'Loading...' e em baixo a barra e gostaria de apagar todas as linhas por baixo de 'Loading...'. Se não existir nenhuma forma de fazer isso gostaria de uma indicaçao de como fazer uma barra melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a lib [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) ela tem umas barras bem interessantes e pode ser que o resultado evite a situação que você encontrou, no link deles você tem até um gif com exemplos de uso da lib.

Aqui, um exemplo simples:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
    for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
        ...
```

Comment: Caso não funcione, mostre como ficou para que eu possa te ajudar.